# Efficient algorithms for mutual, inverse, or round-trip Personalized PageRank

Tags: graphs, reference-request

I'd like to implement a similarity between two nodes (X and Y) of a graph based on a simple extension of the Personalized PageRank algorithm, either:

1. (Mutual PageRank): the product of the PPR of Y with respect to X and of X with respect to Y, or
2. (Round-trip PageRank): the probability of a resetting random walk completing a round-trip back to X after having passed through Y.

I've found some nice references for efficient PPR calculation, but I'm having trouble finding papers that optimize the search for nodes with high inverse PPR (as would be useful for the first option). If the second option has had anything published on it, I've been unable to hit on the right search term for it.

I'm not ideologically stuck to these exact definitions; I'd would be interested in references to any algorithms that are efficient and qualitatively similar.